# AWS ECS nodejs app propagate log level to PaperTrail using Logspout

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ecs, syslog

I'm running apps on docker which they are nodejs/express apps. They are doing logging in info, debug, error but when i open PaperTrail all of log levels are messed like **debug** is **error** which is weird...

How can i change how log levels are mapped or being properly propagated from my apps to papertrail?

Looking at documentation but cannot see anything related to log levels: https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout

does this only work on STDOUT/STDERR and why debug is in error?